# SVG path from file

Tags: javascript, html, svg

Has anyone idea how export path from .svg file by using JS?

In my Angular project I have a lot of svg files, and in different cases I'll must use different svg paths. I'll use this for example like **"M351,5 L351,560.305 C316.247,560.302 281.494,560.301 ..."**.

If i'll open .svg with any text editor i'll see this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0" y="0" width="350" height="600" viewBox="0, 0, 350, 600">
  <g id="Layer_1">
    <path d="M351,5 ..." fill="#0A0B09"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

How can I export path's "d" attribute from svg file by using only JS?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_getelementsbytagname.asp + http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_getattribute.asp

Comment: If you include this in your HTML directly as a Node, you can simply use `svg.querySelector('path[d]').getAttribute('d')` to pull out the string. You can use an ajax request to get the SVG file externally and then store it inside an element (doesnt even have to be attached to the DOM)